# Dynamic cast from custom object to sqlite line

Tags: java, android, reflection, android-sqlite

I have a movie table which has many columns and a class that represents the table with the same columns/fields types in the same order (one int for id and all other are strings) I have this code that tries to insert a record of a movie from an object `movie` into the database.
I get a problem that says the method `put` can't take that group or arguments `(String, capture#2-of ?)` is there anything better or a little worse than that to solve my problem? 

 `EDIT:`can you explain me why am I wrong?

```
ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
Field[] fields = movie.getClass().getFields();
for(int i = 0; i < fields.length; i++)
{
    contentValues.put(allColumns[i], fields[i].getType().cast(fields[i].get(movie)));
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`fields[i].getType().cast(fields[i].get(movie))` returns type Object and there is no overload for put(...) that takes an Object as its second argument.

When using content values add(...) methods, you should first convert your values to primitive types such as int, String, boolean, long or byte[]

You could serialize your data to a blob (as an array of byte) or some other representation such as String.

EDIT: Please see comments, it seems that Field.getType() returns a generic Class which you will need to cast before calling cast(), ie:-

```
Class<String> fieldType = (Class<String>) fields[i].getType();
```

But this will not help you get further since you need to know the type up front, what you could do is something like this instead:

```
ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
Field[] fields = movie.getClass().getFields();
for(int i = 0; i < fields.length; i++)
{
        Class<?> fieldType = fields[i].getType();

        if(String.class.isAssignableFrom(fieldType)) {
            contentValues.put(allColumns[i], (String) fields[i].get(movie));
        } else if(Integer.class.isAssignableFrom(fieldType)) {
            contentValues.put(allColumns[i], (Integer) fields[i].get(movie));
        }
        ...and so on for all types
}
```

Comment: From the documentation, [`Class.cast(Object)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Class.html#cast(java.lang.Object)) is parametrized and should return an instance of the Class.  Then, [`Field.getType()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/reflect/Field.html#getType()) returns a `Class<?>`. I think the **<?>** parameter is causing the problem here.

Comment: Yes your right, in that case it would be inferred from the assignment, but since its not assigned ContentValues cannot figure out what overload to use, I will update my answer thanks for pointing that out

Comment: Actually scratch my last comment, your right, Field.getType() returns <?> and he needs to cast the Field.getType() to the target type before calling cast

Answer (score 0):

You could use something like [ORMLite](http://ormlite.com/sqlite_java_android_orm.shtml) to manage your database queries.
Here is some [documentation](http://ormlite.com/javadoc/ormlite-core/doc-files/ormlite_4.html) to use it with Android

Comment: it might help me do my job, but I really have to know why my code isn't working, ORMLite must use instanceOf methods, and I want to avoid them

Comment: ORMLite allows you to specify the desired columns type in the field annotations, and SQLite does not *really* use column typing, so I wouldn't be so sure about the instanceOf methods (didn't look at the source code though).